# .sketch file to .svg from PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app

is .svg the same as a .sketch file format?

Someone asked me to convert a png file to a .sketch file format

so i recreated it in illustrator and saved as .svg

If that okay or what should i have done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, sketch and svg are different, though they're both vector formats. However, sketch should be able to open a .svg and edit it without much problems.

Comment: Okay thanks for that info.. Was much helpful :)